# Pandas sort column names by first character after delimiter

Tags: pandas

I want to sort the columns in a df based on the first letter after the delimiter '-'

```
df.columns = ['apple_B','cat_A','dog_C','car_D']

df.columns.sort_values(by=df.columns.str.split('-')[1])
TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda s: s.str.split('-')[1])
ValueError: User-provided `key` function must not change the shape of the array.
```

Desired columns would be:

```
'cat_A','apple_B','dog_C','car_D'
```

Many thanks!

I needed to sort the index names and then rename the columns accordingly:

```
sorted_index = sorted(df.index, key=lambda s: s.split('_')[1])
# reorder index
df = df.loc[sorted_index]
# reorder columns
df = df[sorted_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with the extracted part of the string as `key`:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda s: s.str.extract('_(\w+)', expand=False))
```

Output columns:

```
[cat_A, apple_B, dog_C, car_D]
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my dataset

Comment: @skiventist can you provide a reproducible example for which is doesn't work? This should work (and does work with the provided example: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['apple_B','cat_A','dog_C','car_D'])`)

Comment: I just see that you use `-` in your example code but have `_` in your example, which one is it? Update my code with `'-(\w+)'` if you have indeed a dash…

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
df.columns = ['apple_B','cat_A','dog_C','car_D']

new_cols = sorted(df.columns, key=lambda s: s.str.split('-')[1])
df = df[new_cols]
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort the index and columns with this method?